# Can a class extend two or more classes

Tags: objective-c

Can a class extend two or more classes in Objective-C?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Objective-C does not allow multiple inheritance.

You could use protocols to achieve whatever you are trying.

Answer (score 1):

Categories could also be used (on a common superclass).

Comment: Hi. The generic case would be to just create a category on NSObject. I have seen this done in the past for very generic behaviors that are desired for all classes.